# How do I replace my nested for loop with broadcasting?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, pycharm, array-broadcasting

I have two different matrices of unequal sizes and I want each element in one matrice to interact with the second matrice differently. Can I replace the nested for-loops with broadcasting? I want to ideally avoid a nested for loop.

```py
values=[[33,23,0.6,0.8,1.5],[34,25,0.9,0.7,1.6]]
points=[[0.2,19.8],[0.6,19.8]]

for i in points:
   for j in values:
      pa_x = j[0]-i[0]
      pa_y = j[1]-i[1]
```

Comment: What is broadcasting?

Comment: @LoukasPap https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: what is the *output you want here?*

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the nested for loop with broadcasting in this case. Broadcasting is a powerful feature in NumPy that allows you to perform element-wise operations between arrays of different shapes.

```
import numpy as np

values = np.array([[33, 23, 0.6, 0.8, 1.5], [34, 25, 0.9, 0.7, 1.6]])
points = np.array([[0.2, 19.8], [0.6, 19.8]])

# Broadcasting to subtract points from values
pa_x = values[:, 0] - points[:, 0][:, np.newaxis]
pa_y = values[:, 1] - points[:, 1][:, np.newaxis]
```

np.newaxis is used to add a new axis to points[:, 0] and points[:, 1], so that they can be broadcasted properly when subtracted from values[:, 0] and values[:, 1], respectively.

After running this code, pa_x and pa_y will contain the differences between each element in values and each element in points, without using a nested for loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Your two answers here appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues. m